# Redirect page with location.href

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect one url using JavaScript for passing values to Java code using

```
location.href = "/something/uId=" + Idvalue + "time=" + "timeValue"
```

Here I am checking from two radio buttons that are today and Week radio buttons.

It is working fine for week and passing id and time value i.e., `200`(example), `week`(Example).

But when it comes to today option it is passing only time value only. I tried the following ways

```
location.href += "&uId=" + uId;
// and 
location.href += "time=" + today + "&uId=" + uId;
```

But it is passing only today only. I was surprised to see additional variables `timeframe=today&x=26&y=4` but I did't pass these x and y values.

Comment: `location.href+="&uId="` means `location.href=location.href+"&uId="`, so `location.href="Earlier location.herf(current link)"+"&uId="`

Comment: Can you add your radio buttons code and how are you getting values for them. Complete code will help.

Comment: this is for today i.e first radiobutton  **if(timeframeform.timeframe[0].checked==true){
   alert('Uid is at 1 '+uId);
   location.href+="&uId="+uId; 
  }**

Comment: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm

Comment: @if(timeframeform.timeframe[0].checked==true){
   alert('Uid is at 1 '+uId);
   location.href+="&uId="+uId; 
  }

Comment: Can you give your full javascript code and html form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `x` and `y` variables comes because you have image button.

About your redirect page, try as follows:

```
location.href = '/something?uId='+ Idvalue +'&time='+ TimeValue;
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response ,yes i  have image button in place of submit but how it takes values for X and Y  because these values are varying every time.And what is difference between.My Url and u r given URL

Comment: timevalue=today&uId=61 this is the Url working if we enter it manually.but if using your code it is appending again x  and Y values ** /something?timevalue=today&x=21&y=8#61 **

Comment: `x` and `y` variables is the position clicked on this image button. For example if your image button width=50 and height=20, then by clicking on it somewhere in the center would give you something like `x=25&y=10`. The difference between my URL and your is that I have `?` sign before I start giving GET parameters to my URL and I separate each parameter with `&` sign.

Comment: yes Exactly it is doing Same thing,. Vlad Stratulat.If i remove that image it is working fine but i have to use image as well.

Comment: I don't understand your task. You need to use javascript to redirect user to another page, but somehow you get `x` and `y` variables. Those variables appears only if you submit your form in a normal way. That means that your javascript isn't redirecting before form submit. So what exactly do you need? Redirect user before form is submitted or after when you have GET parameters?

Comment: Hi Vlad Stratulat, problem solved.Thanks for your help.After passing parameters only i have to redirect that parameters to java code.Any how it is working.fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what has gone wrong here. If `uId` is not being passed, I think that it is a different area of the code (whatever is responsible for setting `uId` that has broken.

The way you are forming URLs seems to be incorrect. The queryString of a URL should look like this:

```
url.com?firstArgName=firstArgValue&secondArgName=secondArgValue& ....
```

So your initial line should look like this:

```
location.href="/something?uId="+Idvalue+"&time="+timeValue
```

If your webserver is working in a standard way.

Comment: i had done previously as same as you provided but it is working fine for only one option i.e this week.not for another i.e today